# Customizing schema with Sync Framework

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

i sync a database via wcf service to sql ce databases on my clients.
however, i don't want the schema generated on the client side to be the
same, as the one on the server.
is there a way to customize the schema returned to the client syncproviders?

Comment: You asked this question a while back...did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Column filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb726003.aspx)?

It allows you to sync only a subset of the rows or columns between 2 databases.